# Better overview of visual WPF resources

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

Given: there are several resource dictionaries in WPF solution with various resources (vector graphics):

```
<ResourceDictionary ...>
    <Canvas x:Key="SvgWarning" ... />
    <Canvas x:Key="SvgError" ... />
    <Canvas x:Key="SvgOk" ... />
 ...
    <Path x:Key="PathBullet" ... />
    <Path x:Key="PathMinus" ... />
 ...
```

Dictionaries are added to application resources. Those vector graphics are then used in different windows, user controls, etc.

Problem: over years of development they become too many. It's hard to tell how exactly which one looks like and I'd like to have better overview of them. E.g. if I'd have jpg-files referenced by a project then I could simply use windows explorer to preview how each looks like.

Currently I have to remember (or find) keys and then type it:

---

[image]

---

and only then I can see how it looks like. Silent intellisense is not a real problem (but a bonus points of course), because I simply want to preview images even before I decide to add one to a button.

Question: how can I organize it so I can quickly see *which "witch" is which*?

I can make a designer-only window (not used at run-time) and add all images there MANUALLY; by clicking each I can then see its key in xaml. Can I enumerate resources, detect which one is image (but not e.g. a style) and add it to such window? Maybe the way it's organized now is bad?

I don't need a concrete solution, rather a push in the right direction, hints from someone who has similar problem and have solved it.

Comment: Giving them a clear name which allows to identify which ui element this resource belongs to sounds like an option here. E.g. `Window.ToolbarBackground` or `Button.BorderMouseOver`

Comment: Your last sentence makes this question very opinion based, therefor here is my opinion: Move all of that to a separate library and make a proper documentation with visual reference to all styles and perhaps icons(pictures) or colors. That way it can be reused in any project and not only by you, but whoever is going to need it.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, good idea, but name is not enough. Taking example with jpg-files, I'd still want to see them. And I can't *preview* all images in resource dictionary (even if I could it would still be not very comfortable).

Comment: @NawedNabiZada, for *stale* (or finished) product might work, but if you continuously developing it you don't want to add hassle like this. With your proposal adding a new *image* would be a nightmare. If I'd have many projects and big library I'd still looking for a solution to ease process of adding new image. Proper documentation? hmm.. how do I do documentation for resource dictionaries? Manually? No way, sorry.

Comment: Well again... It's all opinion based. It will eventually work if you need to reuse Styles, Templates, Icons etc. otherwise you will be having the same code in each project.